Looking for a citation for this simple generalization of the Markov bound to non-negative super-martingales
Does anybody know a reference for the following theorem?

Theorem 1. Let $(X_t)_{t=0}^\infty$ be a non-negative supermartingale.
Then, for any constant $c > 0$, the event $(\exists
> t)\, X_t \ge c$ has probability at most $E[X_0]/c$.

The theorem generalizes the standard Markov bound.
The theorem is not hard to prove, but I haven't been able to find it in the literature.

This post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4868201/proof-of-doobs-maximal-inequality-for-positive-supermartingales refers to your inequality as Doob's Maximal inequality for a positive supermartingale.

Thank you!  From that name I was able to find a suitable reference here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality#Further_inequalities :  Revuz & Yor 1999, Corollary II.1.6 and Theorem II.1.7.  If you'd like to make an answer out of this please go ahead.  If not I can do it.

Please go ahead.

Correction.  The citation I gave is incorrect.  The correct citation is to the same text, but Page 58, "(1.15) Exercise (Maximal inequality for positive supermartingales)."  Also, I apparently am unable to post an answer (probably I don't have enough reputation).
